# How to extend the area a VBA script imports from a csv file?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have to edit a VBA script I did not write myself.
That's why I do not really know what to do (and I tried a lot).

The code:

```
Sub Datei_Auslesen_Modul1()
On Error GoTo errorhandler
Dim fso As Object, Dat As Object, i As Long, Blatt As Byte
  Dim txt As String, x As Integer, y As Byte, alt As Integer
  Dim Pfad_Maxforce As String
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Pfad_Maxforce = InputBox("Bitte Pfad zum maxforce_Archiv (SICHERUNGEN) angeben.", "Maxforce_MT_FINAL_SIcherungen", "E:\05_Messungen\02_Skripte\07_Versuchsauswertung\01_Maximalkraftauslesen\maxforce_MT_FINAL_Sicherungen\")

  Set Dat = fso.OpenTextFile(Pfad_Maxforce & Sheets("Daten_gesammelt").Range("k9"), 1, False) 'Dateiname aus Zelle g8 in Blatt

  i = 0
  Do While Dat.AtEndOfStream <> True
    ' Tabellenblatt ermitteln
    Blatt = (i \ 65536) + 1   
    txt = Dat.ReadLine
    alt = 0
    y = 0
    For x = 1 To Len(txt)
      If Mid(txt, x, 1) = ";" Then
      Worksheets("max_force_auslesen_Modul1").Cells((i Mod 65536) + 1, y + 1) = Mid(txt, alt + 1, x - alt - 1)
      alt = x
      y = y + 1
      End If
    Next x
    Worksheets(Blatt).Cells((i Mod 65536) + 1, y + 1) = Mid(txt, alt + 1, x - alt - 1)
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  Dat.Close
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Exit Sub
```

The Problem is, the Script does not import tha last column of the csv file. Where do I have to change the parameters?
Cheers.

Comment: Re-reading the code, it looks like it should already be going to the extents of the file, as `Len(txt)` would suggest.  Have you tried stepping through the code?  In the VB IDE, press F11 until you expect it to grab the final column, then check the variable values.  You can also utilize the watch, right click on variables and click add watch.

Comment: the value of `y` is only going up to 14, but the last column is no. 15.
May it be, that the problem is, that after the last value in the csv file there is no `;` ?

Comment: I would assume then that it is going to 15 but the IF statement is causing it to ignore the content of the cell.  Keep stepping through, see if it gets to 15.

Comment: The FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile method doesn't care about the general content, but your code does.

Comment: no, `y` goes from 14 to 0

Comment: I think the code after the For Loop:
...
`Next x
Worksheets(Blatt).Cells((i Mod 65536) + 1, y + 1) = Mid(txt, alt + 1, x - alt - 1)`
...
should add the last column but it doesn't

Comment: Let me explain this better.  y cannot increment to 15 if the cell does not have a semi-colon, because y is incremented INSIDE of the if-statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change this if condition like this:

```
 If Mid(txt, x, 1) = ";" Or x = Len(txt) Then
```

Comment: I had thought about that but we don't know the content, or how far the actual "used" cells extend out to.  There probably was a specific reason they were using semi-colons to parse specific cells.  I think he can move the `y = y + 1` outside of the if statement safely.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you:) (I tried to move y=y+1 outside.. doesn't work)

Comment: @dalleaux Be warned, if you add more columns again, this method will be invalid.  This method will read all the columns with a semi-colon and the last column only.

Comment: Its not really a smart solution but I do not fully agree though with your point that it will not work when there are more columns added. No matter how many more columns are added... it will work as it is comparing x with the len(txt) and not a hard coded length. Or am I missing something here?